# What's one code base and rule them all in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter. But I heard that flutter creates android, ios, web app with one code.
But my question is one code means without changing any bit of code and it'll run on all.
Or some thing else.
Please help me for that

Comment: Yes. For a very simple project, you wouldn't need to edit any bit of code to run on ios, android, web and windows (and others, I believe, but haven't tried).

Answer (score 1):

You can, without changing any bit of code, run it on any platform. (iOS, Android, Web, Windows, Linux, MacOS).

You can even hot reload all those platform at the same time if you're crazy enough.

As for real application, you ll need to create multiples layout in your codebase to support web/desktop AND mobile at the same time for exemple.